# beautifulsoup extract by class value text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract paragraph data based on h2 class value. Below is html code.

```
<div class="myClass">
<div itemprop="reviewBody" class="review-body">
<h2 class="h3">Test1</h2><p>I want to extract this</p>
<h2 class="h3">Test2</h2><p>Dont want to extract</p>
<h2 class="h3">Test3</h2><p>I want to extract this too</p>
< /div>
< /div>
```

Output should look like

```
Test 1    | I want to extract this
Test 3    | I want to extract this too
```

Below is my code, but it extracts all tests(Test1, test2, test3). How to extract data based on h2 text?

```
soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all(class_="myClass")

test1= [] 

for item in divs[0].find_all('h2',class_="h3"):
    test1.append(item.text.strip())
print(test1)
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear: what's the test for excluding one element? Is it always the one in the middle? The second one? Some word in the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to apply an additional condition on the `h2` text. You can use `text` argument of the `.find_all()`, which could hold a list of texts you want to match, e.g.:

```
for h2 in soup.find_all('h2', class_='h3', text=['Test1', 'Test3']):
    print(h2.get_text())
```

If you want to additionally get to the following paragraph, you could use [`find_next_sibling()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
for h2 in soup.find_all('h2', class_='h3', text=['Test1', 'Test3']):
    print(h2.find_next_sibling('p').get_text())
```